# Solr Importing database field issues . how to I use postgres pgpool connection?

Tags: java, postgresql, lucene, solr, pgpool

I am using postgres database and pgpool . Postgres database port : 5432 is woking fine. But 
I am using Pgpool port : 9999 is Not Working.

MY importing xml file (**myproduct.xml**)
**Working**

```
<dataSource name="jdbc" driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxxxx"
        user=" xxxxx " password="xxxxx" readOnly="true" autoCommit="false" />
```

**Not Working**

```
<dataSource name="jdbc" driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9999/xxxxx"
    user=" xxxxx " password="xxxxx" readOnly="true" autoCommit="false" />
```

It is pgpool problem or solr problem? please any onle let me know the issues and
How to I salve pgpool this problem?

Comment: Is there any error? that might help us to understand your problem, it looks that you could not connect on port 9999 and it might due to other application already establish connection on that port.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely you are running into an SSL issue. PGPool on port 9999 is normally configured with SSL enabled.  You can try adding:

?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

to the end of your url, making it look something like:

jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9999/xxxxx?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

However in my case that still doesn't seem to work, but it is worth a try.